# Global storage array - setting length on declaration vs inside a function

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays

I have a global storage array of 64 entries, which I declare as follows:

```
uint256[64] globalArr;
```

However, its length really depends on a constant variable in my code:

```
uint8 constant MAX_VAL = 63;
```

If anyone wishes to change this value at some point in the future, then they need to change it also in the array declaration.

So ideally, I would like to declare them as follows:

```
uint8 constant MAX_VAL = 63;
uint256[MAX_VAL+1] globalArr;
```

However, the language does not support this type of declaration.

My alternative is to declare the array without length, and set it right before filling all the entries:

```
uint256[] globalArr;

function MyContract() // constructor
{
    globalArr.length = MAX_VAL+1;
    globalArr[0] = ...;
    globalArr[1] = ...;
    ...
    globalArr[63] = ...;
}
```

At this point, I should emphasize, that the array contents are computed separately, in a Python script which then auto generates the entire function. So the programmer needs not worry about changing these assignments as a result of changing `MAX_VAL`.

And I would just like to add the `globalArr.length = MAX_VAL+1;` to the Python script (of course, I can just let the script handle the `uint256[64] globalArr;` declaration, but this resides **outside** the function, and the script is essentially designated to auto-generate the function alone).

So my question is:

Is there any performance impact in using my desired coding structure:

```
uint256[] globalArr;

function MyContract() // constructor
{
    globalArr.length = MAX_VAL+1;
    ...
}
```

Over my current coding structure:

```
uint256[64] globalArr;

function MyContract() // constructor
{
    ...
}
```

Intuitively, I feel like my current coding structure is equivalent to a static allocation in C, while my desired coding structure is equivalent to a dynamic allocation in C. So I am wondering if this could potentially lead to any runtime impact of some sort.

Thank you very much!